# The existence of differential operator of the form $AB=0$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

We define $\mathcal A$ is a differential operator of order $n$ with variable coefficients if
$$ \mathcal A:=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq n}A_\alpha (x) D^\alpha $$
where $\alpha$ is an muti-index and $A_\alpha(x)$ is a matrix in suitable dimension and $D^\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th differential operator.

Next, take $\mathbb U$ and $\mathbb V$ to be finite dimensional inner product spaces and we denote by $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb U)$ the space of distributions valued in $\mathbb U$. Then we can think $\mathcal A$ is mapping from $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb U)$ to $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb V)$.

We also define, for two differential operators $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal P$, that $\mathcal Q\mathcal P$ is exact if and only if the kernel of $\mathcal Q$ is the image of $\mathcal P$. (which exclude the case $\mathcal Q\equiv 0$ or $\mathcal P\equiv 0$ and also the case that image of $\mathcal P$ is only a subset of Kernel of $\mathcal Q$)

My questions are:

(1): given any differential operator $\mathcal P$ of order $n$, $n\in\mathbb N$, is there exists a number $m\in \mathbb N$ such that there exists a differential operator $\mathcal Q$ with order $m$ and $\mathcal Q\mathcal P$ is exact?

(2): similarly, given any differential operator $\mathcal Q$ of order $m$, $m\in\mathbb N$, is there exists a number $n\in \mathbb N$ such that there exists a differential operator $\mathcal P$ with order $n$ and $\mathcal Q\mathcal P$ is exact?

PS: this question come from the observation from this [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-2011-10607-5), section $4$, theorem 4.1. Note that in theorem 4.1 part (i), it says $\mathcal Q\mathcal P=0$ is different then what I have here. In theorem 4.1 part (i) it only means that the kernel of $\mathcal Q$ contains the image of $\mathcal P$, but I want them to be equal.

PPS: In that paper, example 4.2 gives an counterexample that there exists a 1st order operator $\mathcal P$ such that there does not exist a 1st order operator $\mathcal Q$ such that $\mathcal Q\mathcal P=0$. But in my question I don't want to limit the order of operator. If there are no 1st order $\mathcal Q$, could there be a 2nd order $\mathcal Q$ such that $\mathcal Q\mathcal P$ is exact?

Thank you!

Comment: $AB = 0$ implies only that the image of $B$ is a subset of the kernel of $A$. They don't have to be equal.

Comment: @DeaneYang I want the kernel of $A$ is exactly the image of $B$. I also updated my post. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Suggestions for improving your question: 

1. $P = \mathcal{A}$ (I assume)
2. Are your operators acting on scalar valued functions?
3. You don't really need to mention degrees at all.

Comment: For some operators (e.g. deRham or Dolbeaut) there is an explicit resolution , i.e. a sequence of diff. op. where each consecutive two are (locally!) exact. Moreover operators in these resolutions don't act on scalar valued functions.

Comment: And just to be clear: What do you mean when you say "kernel" and "image" ? On what space do A and B act? Column space of the right dimension, yes. But what are the entries? Smooth functions? Distributions? Anything else?

Comment: As the comments above, there are a lot of issues with your question as posed. For example, a simple one is that whether exactness, as you define it, holds depends on the domain of the operator. For example, the exterior derivative of differential forms is exact if and only if the corresponding deRham cohomology group vanishes. For other operators, the exactness depends on even more than just the domain. In general, exactness, as you define it, is a rather subtle phenomenon that is understood fully only for special operators.

Comment: One possible question might be whether "local exactness" holds, which means at any point in the domain there exists a (sufficiently small) neighborhood of that point on which the operators are exact.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments guys. I'll completely re-type my question tonight. Hopefully at that time it will make more sense. I apologize for this poor edition...

Comment: @DeaneYang: Now I'm curious. On what other things does the exactness depend? Various function spaces on which the differential operator can act?

Comment: Vit, I'm not familiar with the details, but it seems to me that the cohomology associated with any elliptic complex of differential operators, such as Dolbeault cohomology as well as operators on vector bundles, depend on more than the topology of the domain.

Comment: @DeaneYang I add more informations and some reference. Please have a look. Thank you!

Comment: It's bad form to link to the PDF if a link to the abstract will do.

Comment: @wisher, you should look at reference 9 of the paper by Gustafson (Tarkhanov, _Complexes of differential operators_). It probably has more information than you ever wanted to know about such complexes. Unfortunately, it's only wishful thinking that a simple variation of your question will make the answer Yes, as can be seen from the examples of Robert Bryant. The conditions under which such an 'exactness' result might hold are very subtle (for variable coefficient operators) and lead to the big Spencer theory for overdetermined PDEs and open problems (Spencer's conjecture).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the answer to (2), generally speaking is 'no'.  For example, consider the case of $\mathcal{A}$ being the Cauchy-Riemann operator:
$$
\mathcal{A}(u,v) = (u_x - v_y,\ u_y+v_x).
$$
The kernel of $\mathcal{A}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set of $(u,v)$ such that $u+iv$ is a holomorphic function of $z = x + i y$.  Now, if $\mathcal{B}$ were a linear operator on some space of smooth functions to pairs of smooth functions, in order for it to be exact, the image of $\mathcal{B}$ would have to, in particular, consist only of real-analytic functions, but this is clearly not possible since, if $\mathcal{B}$ is nonzero, its image will necessarily contain compactly supported smooth functions.

The answer to (1) is also 'no', without further assumptions.  For example, let $\mathcal{B}(u) = xu$ where $u$ is a function of a single variable $x$.  The image of $\mathcal{B}$ (an operator of order zero) is all smooth functions vanishing at the origin.  It is clear that this image is not the kernel of any differential operator $\mathcal{A}$ of the specified type.